# How to create shapes in android and add text and image on the shape?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to create the green shape and add text and an image on top of the green shape. Like this example: 
[image]

I created the this example in photoshop and I tried to use it as an `<ImageView>` but the image always look blurry and so, I decided to re-create it using .xml

I know how to create a circle, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
android:useLevel="false" >
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

<stroke
    android:width="10dp"
    android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options but if I understand you correctly you would like to have one `View` which will fill the whole screen, show some text in addition to the picture and last not least have this curved background.

To achieve this, one can create a custom `View` which extends from `ImageView` (or as Android Studio recommends it, from `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView`). Extending from `ImageView` means we'll have to take care of the background and the text, handling the picture will be no problem.

IMO it's better to give the custom `View` a set of parameters and have it draw the background using a [`Path`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path) than to use a `ShapeDrawable` because this way one can first evaluate the `View`'s bounds and then  determine where exactly the curve should be drawn.

First, let's introduce some dimension values in res/values/dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="clipped_circle_deviation">100dp</dimen>
<dimen name="clipped_circle_padding_top">60dp</dimen>
```

Then, the Activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.example.customviews.views.ClippedCircleView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/test"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/clipped_circle_padding_top"
        android:scaleType="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The picture I used for testing:
[image]

And what it looks like (I'm sure the text needs some fine tuning but that's another question)

[image]

ClippedCircleView.java

```
public class ClippedCircleView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public static final String TAG = "ClippedCircle";
    private static final int INNER_EDGE_WEIGHT = 2;
    private static final int OUTER_EDGE_WEIGHT = 3;

    private int measuredWidth;
    private int measuredHeight;
    private Paint innerPaint;
    private Paint outerPaint,;
    private Paint textPaint;
    private Path path;

    public ClippedCircleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ClippedCircleView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ClippedCircleView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        setWillNotDraw(false);

        path = new Path();

        innerPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        innerPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        innerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        outerPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        outerPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        outerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        textPaint.setTextSize(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.clipped_circle_textsize));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        measuredWidth = right - left;
        measuredHeight = bottom - top;
        float innerEdgeLength = INNER_EDGE_WEIGHT/ (OUTER_EDGE_WEIGHT * 1.0f) * measuredHeight;
        path.moveTo(0,0);
        path.lineTo(0, innerEdgeLength);
        float deviation = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.clipped_circle_deviation);
        path.quadTo(measuredWidth*0.5f, innerEdgeLength + deviation, measuredWidth, innerEdgeLength);
        path.lineTo(measuredWidth, 0);
        path.lineTo(0,0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, measuredWidth, measuredHeight, outerPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(path, innerPaint);
        canvas.drawText("Hello!", 32, 80, textPaint);
        canvas.drawText("Welcome to", 32, 160, textPaint);
        canvas.drawText("My App", 32, 240, textPaint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I expand the height of the green shape? Right now the image position is not low enough

Comment: @JMASTER B- either you increase the deviation dimension or you change the INNER_... and/or OUTER_... constants in the code snippet so that innerEdgeLength increases. The magic is happening in onLayout() where the Path is built

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly write text in shape drawable except converting it to `bitmap` then write the text. If you really want to create it with `Drawable`, you should do it using Adobe Illustrator and export it as `svg`. Then it is possible to import `svg` as **Android Vector Drawable** (File -> New -> Vector Asset -> Local file -> ...).

Comment: If I do that then I will be able to add whatever I want on it?

Comment: Yes, you can do whatever you want. But unfortunately there is some problems with gradient and shadows.

Comment: The best way I think is to write the text in a `TextView`.